# SQL update query in C# foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I want to run an `UPDATE` SQL query within a C# `foreach` loop, such as:

```
var alterQuery = $@"
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'MyColumn' AND Object_ID = Object_ID('MyTable'))
    ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD [MyColumn] nvarchar(255)
    ";

using (var connection = myConnection)
{
    connection.Execute(alterQuery);

    foreach (var obj in myObjects)
    {
        var query = $@"UPDATE [MyTable]
                       SET [MyColumn] = '{obj.Val}'
                       WHERE [ID] = '{obj.ID}'
                      ";

        // note: my Execute method uses ExecuteNonQuery() behind the scenes
        connection.Execute(query);
    }
}
```

But, I receive the following SQL Exception. I receive it when there are two or more values in `myObjects` but not when there is only one:

> Additional information: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name MyColumn in table MyTable is specified more than once.

I believe it may be due to the queries running simultaneously and trying to access the same column (MyColumn). Should I be running my queries in such a way that each must wait until the previous completes?

How can I successfully run these queries?

Comment: Print out the query being generated and make sure you can run that generated SQL successfully in an SSMS window connected to the same database.

Comment: Theres no evidence in your code of any parallel running, so thats not your problem.

Comment: From the minimal code you posted it doesn't look like it's queries running simultaneously

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have `CREATE` query that triggers this error?  What character set is used for your column names?

Comment: @PM77-1 I am not using a `CREATE` query but am using an `ALTER` query before my foreach loop. I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: @pmbAustin It works properly in SSMS...

Comment: Show the code that executes the ALTER. Are you hard coding the column name?

Comment: @Crowcoder It is within the `using (var connection = myConnection)`. It is just another call: `connection.Execute(alterQuery);`. In my `ALTER` statement (as shown in the question), I am hard-coding the column name, yes.

Comment: Show the full code including the ALTER code, in its actual location, so we don't have to guess. Clearly that's the call that is causing the issue.

Comment: What about the implementation of Execute()? Do you reset the CommandText? It almost sounds like your command hasn't changed or is appended to.

Comment: @pmbAustin Edited question to add ALTER code.

Comment: This is not good: `using (var connection = myConnection)` because you're indicating that the connection should be disposed when the using block is over, but it's coming from a local variable which is itself held onto in a reference, and that makes no sense. You should NOT cache connections in C#—open a new one each time. The database library will do connection pooling for you, better than you ever could, and will save you the hassle of dealing with connection state.

Comment: Put a `try..catch` around `connection.Execute(alterQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `BEGIN` and `END` around my `ALTER TABLE` query.

Does not work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'MyColumn' AND 
Object_ID = Object_ID('MyTable'))
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD [MyColumn] nvarchar(255)
```

Works:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'MyColumn' AND 
Object_ID = Object_ID('MyTable'))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD [MyColumn] nvarchar(255)
END
```

I find it weird that in the **non-working** case, the only line that the `IF NOT EXISTS`check controls is the `ALTER TABLE MyTable` line, rather than both the `ALTER TABLE MyTable` and the `ADD [MyColumn] nvarchar(255)` lines, which should be interpreted as one statement.